# Laravel: Use absolute path for cache folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We are using Lavarel 5 and would like cache folder separate from main application (probably even a different drive).

In **config/cache.php** we have:

```
    'file' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        //'path' => storage_path('framework/cache'),
        'path' => storage_path('<ABSOLUTE_PATH>'),
    ],
```

However, Laravel in not using `<ABSOLUTE_PATH>`. Instead it creates `framework/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>`. In other words it interprets `<ABSOLUTE_PATH>` as a relative path.

How can we set absolute path for cache?

Comment: Remove `storage_path()` and just set the absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the storage_path function from the string to put an absolute path in...

```
'path' => '/var/www/blah/'
```

Comment: I don't know why there was a downvote on this, but the simple change resolves it.